# How to submit form in browser not with ajax and show alert on form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a wizard form which is validated fine, but on form submission I want it done in the browser not with ajax but when form is successfully submitted it shows the swal alert in the code below. I have added only the part of script from form submission...script is minified.

```js
var WizardDemo=function(){$("#add_wizard");var e,r,i=$("#addemp");return{init:function(){var n;$("#add_wizard"),i=$("#addemp"),(r=new mWizard("add_wizard",{startStep:1})).on("beforeNext",function(r){!0!==e.form()&&r.stop()}),r.on("change",function(e){mUtil.scrollTop()}),r.on("change",function(e){1===e.getStep()&&alert(1)}),e=i.validate({ignore:":hidden",rules:{firstName:{required:!0},lastName:{required:!0},dob:{required:!0},gender:{required:!0},mstatus:{required:!0},employeeLogo:{required:!0},employeeId:{required:!0},loginPassword:{required:!0},mobileNumber:{required:!0},personalEmail:{required:!0},rAddress:{required:!0},city:{required:!0},region:{required:!0},dateoFJoining:{required:!0},employementType:{required:!0},designationName:{required:!0},categoryName:{required:!0},grade:{required:!0},departmentName:{required:!0},idtype:{required:!0},icard:{required:!0},accountName:{required:!0},accountNumber:{required:!0},bankAccount:{required:!0},bankBranch:{required:!0}},messages:{"account_communication[]":{required:"You must select at least one communication option"},accept:{required:"You must accept the Terms and Conditions agreement!"}},invalidHandler:function(e,r){mUtil.scrollTop(),swal({title:"",text:"Please correct the errors in the form and submit again",type:"error",confirmButtonClass:"btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--wide"})}}),(n=i.find('[data-wizard-action="submit"]')).on("click",function(r){r.preventDefault(),e.form()&&(mApp.progress(n),i.ajaxSubmit({success:function(){mApp.unprogress(n),swal({title:"",text:"The application has been successfully submitted!",type:"success",confirmButtonClass:"btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--wide"})}}))})}}}();jQuery(document).ready(function(){WizardDemo.init()});
```

Comment: There's more to the code, it's incomplete.

Comment: Just selected the part from SUBMIT but I have updated to whole code

Comment: "mWizard is not defined", probably un-minify for the question, you can do that after it works.   This is not really Minimal, Verifiable or Complete https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: mWizard is define to move the wizard from step one to step two, which works perfectly, My only problem is disabling the ajax form submission and allowing the browser to submit the forms but when the form is submitted the alert is displayed